# How to define (overload?) predefined sizes (large, x-large, etc.) in CSS?

Tags: css, font-size

Well, CSS font-size property supports some predefined values like xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large, etc.

They are obviously mapped to some fixed values in pixels.

Is there any way to define these corresponding values via CSS stylesheet (as overloading *stock* values)?

For example I would like to make all selectors with `font-size: large` to be like `font-size: 30px`. 
So how to define *large* as *30px* here?

If there is no way to define this via simple CSS Stylesheet how would you perform this mapping dynamically with jQuery?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: See: http://style.cleverchimp.com/font_size_intervals/altintervals.html

Comment: @Diodeus I saw this before posting here but it does not solve this problem.

Comment: I've never actually seen anyone use named font sizes in the wild. You can override the class names, but not the named values.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-size):

**xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large:**
*A set of absolute size keywords based on the user's default font size*

So to have control over these values you need to define a default font. I guess these are just shortcuts to default percentages.

Comment: Yup, and the aren't even the same across browsers and OSes.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Diodeus having never seen these "in the wild" - the popular TinyMCE Advanced plugin for Wordpress uses the preset font-size properties (medium, large, x-large, etc) in its 'Font Size' drop-down box. It would be useful to be able to override the default sizes.

Comment: And that is the reason of my question, because I use TinyMCE and I was trying to figure it out how to define styles which TinyMCE creates (x-large, x-small, etc.). But I managed to change the source of TinyMCE so now it uses other values which are ok for me.